# How can I remove this from the footer?

Tags: html, css

I have this site:

http://dl.dg-site.com/

To see what they say you need a larger monitor or give zoom out in your browser.

I put this picture to see what I mean

http://i57.tinypic.com/xleyo1.png

I want to wipe that thing + title only on the first page

This is code HTML:

```
  <div id="top_footer">


<h2 id="titlu_footer">Fonctionnement des panneaux</h2>
<p id="continut_footer">Les panneaux sont des modules à base de silicium. Bien qu’il en existe d’autres types, mais ceux-ci sont, actuellement, les plus utilisés en raison de leur prix et de leur qualité. Il existe principalement, selon le type de technique utilisée pour la fabrication du panneau et selon le type d’installation à réaliser, deux sortes de panneaux au silicium :</p>

<div id="tabele">
<div id="tabel_first">
       <p id="tabel_first_title">Le Monocristallin</p>
       <p id="tabel_first_content">Les capteurs photovoltaïques sont à base de cristaux de silicium  encapsulés dans une enveloppe en plastique ou en verre.</p>

</div>
<div id="tabel_two">
        <p id="tabel_two_title">Le Polycristallin</p>
        <p id="tabel_two_content">Les capteurs sont à base de polycristaux de silicium, bien moins coûteux à fabriquer que le silicium monocristallin. Ces panneaux ont un rendement plus faible que les monocristallins.</p>

</div>
</div>

</div>
```

I tried to use this code but not working...Disappears everything ... not just text.

```
.page-id-279 #top_footer{display:none;}
```

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is your site so presumably you know how that text got there. Why don't you just edit it out? If you don't know how it got there you have a bigger problem since it's possible your site has been hacked.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "I want to wipe that thing "  - what is 'that thing"? what do you mean by "wipe it"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the white gap with the text in the bottom, just delete these lines from your html:

```
<div id="tabele">
    <div id="tabel_first">
       <p id="tabel_first_title">Le Monocristallin</p>
       <p id="tabel_first_content">Les capteurs photovoltaïques sont à base de cristaux de silicium  encapsulés dans une enveloppe en plastique ou en verre.</p>
</div>
<div id="tabel_two">
    <p id="tabel_two_title">Le Polycristallin</p>
    <p id="tabel_two_content">Les capteurs sont à base de polycristaux de silicium, bien moins coûteux à fabriquer que le silicium monocristallin. Ces panneaux ont un rendement plus faible que les monocristallins.</p>
</div>
```

Just cross-check and make sure there's nothing there that you might need